# Discord.js thinks part of my token is a module

Tags: node.js, discord.js

code that is causing problem: `client.login(process.env.MYTOKENISHERE)`

I can't show the error, because it will reveal my token but I can explain that there are 2 periods/full stops in my bot token. When I try run my bot, it thinks that i am trying to call a module. **How do I fix this?**

Comment: In your `.env` file, do you have the actual bot token wrapped in quotes `"`? If not, that may be the issue.

Comment: Show the error and just hide the token (drawing over it, blurring or any other method) and edit your post to show your .env file (token censored aswell)

Answer (score 0):

the code for you discord token should look something like this:

```
DISCORD_TOKEN=thisisyourverylongtoken
```

note that are no captions around it (i mean these "").
if you could give us the error message that would help aswell.